# @Override on static methods?

Tags: java, annotations

test.java:

```
public class test
{
  protected static void testMethod() {}
}
```

testb.java:

```
public class testb extends test
{
  @Override
  protected static void testMethod() {}
}
```

The result:

```
% javac test.java testb.java
testb.java:5: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
1 error
```

Does @Override not work on static methods? If I remove it, things are fine.

Comment: "Things are fine" very much depends on what your goal and use case is.

Comment: static methods can't be overwritten

Comment: @luk2302 You could have been helpful, but you've been *so* much more.